# Emacs open ssh broken

Tags: ssh, crash

My computer crashed whilst using emacs to ssh open a file. This was not related to emacs but an overheating problem. 
Since then emacs hangs every time I try and open a remote file using ssh

I press ctrl-X ctrl-f

then type :

```
 /ssh:
```

But the colon never appears and emacs hangs.

I have tried copying in the path I want to open and it still hangs.

I  have tried using emacs in the terminal with the  -nw option it still hangs.

I can still open normal files.

I am using ubuntu 16.04

I am an emacs beginner so please bear that in mind in your answers.

Comment: maybe tramp chocked on his history file? Try to delete `.emacs.d/tramp`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that did not work.

Comment: maybe it is not `tramp` but `ido` try to delete (or better just rename) `.emacs.d/ido.last`. You could also try to run `emacs -Q` and then try to `ssh`, it works little different because `ido` is not activated.

Comment: Thanks I did not have an ido.last file but I saw some session files and I removed them and that worked. Thanks for pointing me to the folder.

Comment: I helped you to receive some points eventually. :)

Comment: I have got this problem again and there no .session files to delete so back to trying to solve it.

Comment: Can you do `M-x toggle-debug-on-quit` and then when Emacs hangs, hit `C-g` and see if you get a `*Backtrace*` buffer?

Comment: I ended up installing emacs 26 and getting rid of the emacs 24 that I was using. I am not sure if this fixed it or just because fresh install, if it happens again I will try what you recommend. Damn heat wave!

Answer (score 1):

One time I removed the session files from .emacs.d and that worked.

But I have another instance of this problem and there are no .session files to delete so the problem is still there now.

Comment: Could you please name the files? The next user maybe will be glad about the names.

Comment: The files began session.